# Do AggregateRatings counts in Recipes need to be in Review markup?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, json-ld, user-reviews

If you look at the [recipe rich result documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/recipe) for `aggregateRating`, it says to

> Follow the [Review snippet guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review#review-snippet-guidelines) and list of required and recommended [AggregateRating properties](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review#type_definitions).

Common practice, however, is that the actual reviews are not in the JSON-LD schema at all. Most often, they are tied to a comment that has a name and the rating.

Additionally, I see many sites that allow single click ratings. So, the aggregate ratings do reflect them and the aggregate *is* shown on the page, but there is no individual and unique rating on the page.

I current common practice wrong or correct?
Is there an optimal practice that is outside of current common practice?
Are single click reviews (without an author) ok to add to the `aggregateRating`?

Comment: Which schema format are you using? To me it sounds like you are using JSON-LD - is that correct or are you using Microdata or RDFa?

Comment: You are correct. JSON-LD.

Answer (score 1):

You tell us:

> Common practice, however, is that the actual reviews are not in the
>   JSON-LD schema at all. Most often, they are tied to a comment that has
>   a name and the rating.

It is quite the controversial statement. If you check your Google Guide for Reviews, then you can find many examples of structured data using JSON-LD. E.g.:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "image": "http://www.example.com/catcher-in-the-rye-book-cover.jpg",
  "name": "The Catcher in the Rye",
  "**review**": {
    "@type": "**Review**",
    "**reviewRating**": {
      "@type": "Rating",
      "ratingValue": "5"
    },
    "name": "A masterpiece of literature",
    "author": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "John Doe"
    },
    "datePublished": "2006-05-04",
    "reviewBody": "I really enjoyed this book. It captures the essential challenge people face as they try make sense of their lives and grow to adulthood.",
    "publisher": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "Washington Times"
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can see the obvious elements of the markup for **Review**, but not a comment, such as:

- review
- @type": "Review"
- reviewRating
- reviewBody

If you mean critical reviews, then this is also in the specified Google guide as **[Critic review](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review#critic-review)**.